# react-hooks-forms and default checked radio button

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react hooks forms and has tried most thing to default check a radio button:

```
<FormGroup tag="fieldset">
  <FormGroup check>
    <Label check>
      <Input type="radio" name="isIBAN" innerRef={register} defaultChecked/> IBAN
    </Label>
  </FormGroup>
  <FormGroup check>
    <Label check>
      <Input type="radio" name="isIBAN" innerRef={register} value={false} /> BIC/SWIFT
    </Label>
  </FormGroup>             
</FormGroup>
```

I dont know if you can do it from the default values:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors, setValue, getValues  } = useForm(
  {
    defaultValues:{
      accountNr: "XXXXKB20201555555555",
      bic:"XXXDKKK",
      isIBAN:true
    }
  }
);
```

How is the correct way to default the first radio button to checked? I could make another hook but there must be some built in in react hooks forms?

Comment: When not using a controller, use the `defaultChecked` React prop. (Mentioning since this was my issue and I didn't know about the prop previously.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-pz8oj?file=/src/index.js) for the radio group example.

```
const defaultValues = {
  Native: "",
  TextField: "",
  Select: "",
  ReactSelect: { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
  Checkbox: false,
  switch: false,
  RadioGroup: "female", // default value is the radio input value
  numberFormat: 123456789,
  downShift: "apple"
};
```

```
<section>
  <label>Radio Group</label>
  <Controller
    as={
      <RadioGroup aria-label="gender">
        <FormControlLabel
          value="female"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="Female"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="male"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="Male"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    }
    name="RadioGroup"
    control={control}
  />
</section>
```

Comment: For an up-to-date example, see this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-5h1q5?file=/src/index.js:1571-1602).

Comment: why does all the default checked radio input answers use `material-ui`? is there a non material-ui alternative for default checked radio input?

Answer (score 0):

For the non UI Library, I set the `defaultChecked` as the workaround based on the Hook Form `watch`. Don't know is there any better solution?

Let's say I have a custom Radio Component

```
import type { FC, InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";

import styles from "./styles.module.css";

interface PropTypes {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  description: string;
  icon: JSX.Element;
  name: string;
  value: string;
  theme?: "light" | "dark";
  onChange: (event: InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  defaultChecked?: boolean;
}

const BigSelectBox: FC<PropTypes> = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, PropTypes>(
  function BigSelectBox(
    { id, label, description, icon, value, theme, ...restFields }: PropTypes,
    ref,
  ) {
    return (
      <label
        htmlFor={id}
        className={classNames(
          "flex flex-col rounded-lg border border-gray-200 bg-white shadow-md dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800",
          theme === "dark"
            ? styles["big-select-box-dark"]
            : styles["big-select-box-light"],
          styles["big-select-box"],
        )}
      >
        <input ref={ref} type="radio" id={id} value={value} {...restFields} />
        <span>{icon}</span>
        <div>
          <div>{label}</div>
          <small>{description}</small>
        </div>
      </label>
    );
  },
);

export default BigSelectBox;
```

And in my main component I have define the useForm with the default values and notice I'm using watch to get the current value of `hostedType`

```
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    watch,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitted },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: "asdasdad",
      hostedType: "self-hosted",
    },
  });

  const hostedType = watch("hostedType");
```

And in the component render will be like the below

```
<div className="mb-4 grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-2">
            <Label htmlFor="taskName">VPS Setup</Label>
            <Controller
              name="hostedType"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-2">
                  <BigSelectBox
                    {...field}
                    id="self-hosted"
                    label="Use existing VPS"
                    description="Use existing VPS"
                    value="self-hosted"
                    icon={<FaHouseUser className="text-2xl text-gray-500" />}
                    defaultChecked={hostedType === "self-hosted"}
                  />
                  <BigSelectBox
                    {...field}
                    id="cloud"
                    label="Create new VPS"
                    description="Create new VPS"
                    value="cloud"
                    icon={<FaServer className="text-2xl text-gray-500" />}
                    defaultChecked={hostedType === "cloud"}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            />
          </div>
```